# Streaming video through streaming Engine to virtual reality player provided by google on github

Tags: android, stream, android-videoview, virtual-reality, google-vr

Streaming video through streaming to virtual reality player provided by google on github(https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk) but video wont stream it shows 
None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.

The stream in fine and works on other video player i build.
Stream: [http://104.198.83.123:1935/vim/*definst*/mp4:https/vimersia/vim/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8](http://104.198.83.123:1935/vim/_definst_/mp4:https/vimersia/vim/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8)

ERROR:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
                     com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:262)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:148)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.incrementalPrepareInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:273)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:203)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
                      Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorSampleSource.java:898)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorSampleSource.java:828)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:222)
                         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 E/VrVideoPlayerInternal: 262752989.onPlayerError
                     com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:262)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.SampleSourceTrackRenderer.maybeThrowError(SampleSourceTrackRenderer.java:148)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.incrementalPrepareInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:273)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:203)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
                      Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorSampleSource.java:898)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorSampleSource.java:828)
                         at com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:222)
                         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/SimpleVrVideoActivity: Error loading video: com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.ExtractorSampleSource$UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (WebmExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
```

Java Class:

```
class VideoLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Uri, Options>, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Pair<Uri, Options>... fileInformation) {
        try {
            if (fileInformation == null || fileInformation.length < 1
                    || fileInformation[0] == null || fileInformation[0].first == null) {
                // No intent was specified, so we default to playing the local stereo-over-under video.
                Options options = new Options();
                options.inputType = Options.TYPE_STEREO_OVER_UNDER;
                videoWidgetView.loadVideo(Uri.parse("http://104.198.83.123:1935/vim/_definst_/mp4:https/vimersia/vim/video.mp4/playlist.m3u8"), options);
            } else {
                videoWidgetView.loadVideo(fileInformation[0].first, fileInformation[0].second);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error here is normally due to being unable to locate the file.
            loadVideoStatus = LOAD_VIDEO_STATUS_ERROR;
            // Since this is a background thread, we need to switch to the main thread to show a toast.
            videoWidgetView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast
                            .makeText(SimpleVrVideoActivity.this, "Error opening file. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not open video: " + e);
        }
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?